# Page transparency in turn.js flipbook not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am a novice to Javascript and Jquery, and I'm currently making an interactive book using jquery by following the magazine tutorial here http://technotz.info/tutorials/2012/9/ebook_turn.js/.

For the most part, the book is going quite well but I have run into a small but annoying problem. You see, for this project I'm making an old, leather journal and I want the pages inside the book to be uneven and frayed. Therefore, I want each page to have a transparent edge, showing the edges of the leather cover underneath but I can’t seem to get the transparent edges to work properly.

Using the example code below, if I open the book to page 1, the "transparent" frayed edges look white rather than showing the leather hard-back. If I turn to pages 2 and 3, both frayed pages look transparent as expected but if I hover the mouse over the page turn of page 3, the edges of page 2 turn white and vice versa.

I tried adding transparent background colors of body, #flipbook, #magazine and #magazine.turn-page in CSS as well but same results still apply. What can I do?

Please help as I have been at this for ages and it's the last part I need to fix before I can start writing in my book.

EDIT: I am also using 4th Edition of turn.js if this helps

This is my HTML, Javascript and CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/turn.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-color:transparent;
}
#magazine{
    width:1002px; //dimensions to show magazine
    height:773px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
#magazine .turn-page{
background-color:transparent;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
#flipbook {
    background-color: transparent;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="flipbook">
    <div class="hard" style="background-image:url(pages/cover.png);"> </div> 
    <div class="hard" style="background-image:url(pages/cover.png);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/oldpaperright.png);">Page 1</div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/oldpaperleft.png);">Page 2</div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/oldpaperright.png);">Page 3</div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/oldpaperleft.png);">Page 4</div>
    <div class="hard" style="background-image:url(pages/cover.png);"></div>
    <div class="hard" style="background-image:url(pages/cover.png);"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 1002,
        height: 773,
        autoCenter: true
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As your magazine container is #flipbook I think you should use #flipbook .page as the CSS selector for the page

```
#flipbook .page {
    background: url(pages/oldpaperright.png);
    /* Other CSS Rules */  
}
```

You can use page-wrapper, hard, odd, even, :

```
#flipbook .odd {}
#flipbook .even {}
#flipbook .hard {}
#flipbook .page-wrapper {}
```

Source: 
http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Main_Page

Fiddle mentioned in the turnjs docs:

http://jsfiddle.net/blasten/A9a7E/